# In "Duplicate Objects" what do the "Mirror Editing" and "Proportional Editing" checkboxes do?

Tags: objects, duplicate

In "Duplicate Objects" what do the "Mirror Editing" and "Proportional Editing" checkboxes do?

I'm sorry I couldn't find the answer in any help or searches.